# Zend Studio 9 crashes after Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade - Segmentation fault

Tags: 14.04, segmentation-fault, zend

I have a big problem after upgrading my Ubuntu to the 14.04 version. I am a developer and I use the Zend Studio 9 to develop my web applications.

When I start the Zend Studio 9 I get a Segmentation Error.

```
$ /home/mypc/Scrivania/ZendStudio
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:004] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:004] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:004] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:004] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:004] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
```

How have I to solve this issue? I am trying to debug the dump log, and if I find a solution I'll post here.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution!

Open the `ZendStudio/configuration/config.ini` file and add these two lines:

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=False
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Now Zend Studio works fine.